# C++ compiler error while trying to install python datatable

Tags: python, python-3.x, py-datatable

I am trying to install 'datatable' for python using 'pip' as below, but I am getting error.

```
pip install datatable
```

> Error shown is:
>
> ```
> Find an LLVM installation
>   Environment variable LLVM is not set
>   Environment variable LLVM7 is not set
>   Environment variable LLVM6 is not set
>   Environment variable LLVM5 is not set
>   Environment variable LLVM4 is not set
>   Candidate directory `/usr/local/opt/llvm` not found
>   The build will proceed without Llvm support
>
> Determine the compiler
>   Environment variable `CXX` is not set
>   Environment variable `CC` is not set
>   Llvm installation not found, cannot search for the clang++ compiler
>   'compiler_cxx'
>   Compiler `clang++.exe` is not found
>   Compiler `gcc.exe` is not found
>
> Prepare the environment
> ```

```
SystemExit: Suitable C++ compiler cannot be determined. Please specify a compiler executable in the `CXX` environment variable.
```

I even re-installed VC++ Compiler for Python and also updated:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: setuptoools isn't VC++ Compiler, you must install it by yourself

Comment: which os are you trying to install it on?

Comment: @Sav I installed VC++ for python separately and later Setuptools.

Comment: @TalhaJunaid Windows 10

Comment: You need to install a C compiler like GCC or clang. You might be able to set one of the environment variables required to point to the VC++ compiler binary as a hack.

Comment: I'll suggest installing Visual Studio Build Tools
`https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/52b8cab2-8750-444d-a860-a2e03a891236/554086c6109c4ab6362ef76c76227ec0/vs_buildtools.exe`
`https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/`

Comment: or you can install mingw

Comment: Please read the fine manual (https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#install-on-windows): "Currently datatable does not work on Windows"

Comment: Thanks all. Please post as answers so that I can Accept one.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks for that. Please post as answer so that I can mark it.

Answer (score -1):

If you are on Windows, then datatable will be installable directly via `pip` starting from version 0.11. Right now it is possible to install the development snapshots of the library by following the instructions at https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#install-on-windows.